# c# namespace in variable directories

Tags: c#

I have a directory tree as such:

```
+Enums
|+MyEnums.cs
+Src
 +Model
  +MyModel.cs
```

And I would like to use the *namespace Enums* that I declared in *MyEnums.cs* in the file *MyModel.cs*. But I cannot figure out how to do such, because when using the code

```
using Enums;
```

I constantly get the error/warning that

```
The type or namespace name 'Enums' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

If I use it in the same folder I have no issue, but I would like to use it across a larger directory tree.

Comment: There is no relationship between directory structure and namespaces in C#.

Answer (score 1):

The directory structure of your project and the structure of the namespaces are technically two unrelated things; nevertheless it makes sense to have them organized in parallel, but still they are orthogonal concepts. You have to define a namespace by putting types into it as follows.

```
namespace Enums
{
    // some definitions
}

namespace Enums.MyEnums
{
    // some more definitions
}
```

After populating the namespace, you can import the namesepace with the `using` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a file to a directory like that typically gives you a namespace that is the same as the directory name, but that is not necessarily the case (such as when you move a file from one folder to another).  The namespace is determined like this in the file.  Check what the namespace is and change it to Enums if that's what you want it to be:

```
using System;

namespace Enums
{
    enum Testing
    {
        Test1,
        Test2
    }
}
```